# Expectation of the product of two dependent binomial distributions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, covariance, binomial-distribution

Let $X_i$ (*i* ∈ N) be independent and identically distributed all following a Bin(10, p) distribution for some value p ∈ [0, 1]. Define $Y_n$ := $$\sum_i^m X_i$$

Compute $t_n,m$ = Cov($Y_n$,$Y_m$) for n,m ∈ N where n <= m.

I apologise for my formatting; I hope the question is clear.

In calculating the covariance, I have easily been able to find E($Y_n$) and E($Y_m$), the issue is in calculating E($Y_nY_m$)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By bilinearity of covariance, the covariance of $Y_n$ and $Y_m$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j).$$ Now, if $i\ne j$, $\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=0$ by independence, and for every $i$, $\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_i)=\mathrm{var}(X_i)=\sigma^2$ where surely you can identify $\sigma^2$. Collecting the nonzero terms in the double sum yields finally $$\mathrm{Cov}(Y_n,Y_m)=n\sigma^2.$$ Morale: Better to avoid throwing back the means $E(Y_k)$ or $E(X_k)$ in the pot, using bilinearity of covariance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want the expectation of 
$$(X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n)(X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_m),$$
where $n\le m$.
So we want the expectation of
$$(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)^2 +(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)(X_{n+1}+\cdots+X_m).$$
The second part is easy, by independence.

As for $E((X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)^2)$, the easiest way is to note that this is equal to the variance of $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ plus the square of $E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)$.

Comment: thank you very much, thats excellent.

Comment: You are welcome.  Note that there is a much nicer way of doing it, by bilinearity of covariance. It is a matter of what tools one has.